# Issues configuring a linux browser on remoteseleniumwebdriver on headless machine

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

So,

I am trying to connect a remote selenium webdriver (3.14.0 on both ends)from my machine to the server where the code will be deployed at so that testing is always done with the production version. I know I can just access the deployed version locally but I would like to avoid that workaround.

I have x11 setup properly and I can launch google chrome from console on that machine getting the gnome version of google chrome on my local machine.

When I access the grid console with the default configuration I can see the server supports windows 10 chrome.

I have setup the hub and the node using this guide and they connect to each other properly https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html.

My issue is that even the basic code on said tutorial requesting windows 10 chrome is giving me an error as it is not opening up on the machine(server is linux and should try to open the gnome version of chrome which I can run through x11).

```
package google;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PruebasGoogleRemoto {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static String baseurl, nodeURL;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, MalformedURLException {
        baseurl= "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
        nodeURL="http://172.18.0.90:4420/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capability= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability);
        driver.get(baseurl);
     }
}
```

The error log I am getting is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: UNIX, version: }
Command duration or timeout: 138 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
    at google.PruebasGoogleRemoto.main(PruebasGoogleRemoto.java:36)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: UNIX, version: }
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'PC-10589', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:118)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have gone ahead on the tutorial and attempted to use the default  hub configuration found at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json when launching the hub and then use a defaultnode.json file launching the node.

```
{
      "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "platformName" : "LINUX"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
      "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "maxSession": 5,
      "port": 5555,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "hub": "http://172.18.0.90:4420",
      "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
      "nodePolling": 5000,
      "role": "node",
      "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
      "downPollingLimit": 2,
      "debug": false,
      "servlets" : [],
      "withoutServlets": [],
      "custom": {}
    }
```

After doing this I obtain the following list of available browsers on the grid console.[grid console ignoring the linux browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvB5R.png)

I am now wondering how to add support for a linux browser on my node as I know for a fact I can launch the gnome version of chrome on a windows machine that is connected to this headless machine through terminal using x11.

Comment: why do you set windows platform on linux remote ?

Comment: Because I've tried to set it up to Linux using defaultnode.json config file and it ignores the Linux browser / tells me the machine supports windows applications on the other browsers with undefined platforms. This is addressed at the very end of my post.